# Pojo to xsd generation

Tags: java, xml, xsd, pojo

Is there a library which could generate a xsd schema from a java class?
 Google yields lots of results the opposite ( java classes from xsd ).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JAXB 2.0 allows you to create a XML schema from an annotated Java class.

You'll find some examples at the [AMIS blog](http://technology.amis.nl/blog/2046/using-the-javaxxmlbind-annotations-to-convert-java-objects-to-xml-and-xsd) and at the [JavaPassion site](http://www.javapassion.com/handsonlabs/wsjaxbj2s/#Exercise_2).

Comment: There was some amount of google-fu involved :) No reason to be surprised there.

Comment: Both links are broken

Answer (score 3):

[JiBX](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/jibxtools/schemagen.html) does this

> The schema generator tool first reads
>   one or more JiBX binding definitions
>   and then uses reflection to interpret
>   the structure of the Java classes
>   referenced in the bindings. By
>   combining the binding definitions with
>   the actual class information the
>   schema generator is able to construct
>   one or more XML schemas to represent
>   the documents handled by the bindings.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I would do it:

```
public static void pojoToXSD(Class<?> pojo, OutputStream out) throws IOException, TransformerException, JAXBException {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(pojo);
    final List<DOMResult> results = new ArrayList<>();

    context.generateSchema(new SchemaOutputResolver() {

        @Override
        public Result createOutput(String ns, String file)
                throws IOException {
            DOMResult result = new DOMResult();
            result.setSystemId(file);
            results.add(result);
            return result;
        }
    });

    DOMResult domResult = results.get(0);

    // Use a Transformer for output
    TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();

    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(domResult.getNode());
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(out);
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    transformer.transform(source, result);
}
```

How to use the method above

```
try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        pojoToXSD(NESingleResponse.class, stream);

        String finalString = new String(stream.toByteArray());
        System.out.println(finalString);
    } catch (JAXBException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: Where does the pojo object go?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for giving your method. Just wanted to add complete example.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.SchemaOutputResolver;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMResult;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import test.Test;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException,
            FileNotFoundException {

         JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("test");
         try {
            new Main().pojoToXSD(context, new Test(), System.out);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public void pojoToXSD(JAXBContext context, Object pojo, OutputStream out) 
            throws IOException, TransformerException 
        {
            final List<DOMResult> results = new ArrayList<DOMResult>();

            context.generateSchema(new SchemaOutputResolver() {

                @Override
                public Result createOutput(String ns, String file)
                        throws IOException {
                    DOMResult result = new DOMResult();
                    result.setSystemId(file);
                    results.add(result);
                    return result;
                }
            });

            DOMResult domResult = results.get(0);
            com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DocumentImpl doc = com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DocumentImpl) domResult.getNode();

            // Use a Transformer for output
            TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();

            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(out);
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            transformer.transform(source, result);
        }
}

//---------- below will go in test package

package test;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;




@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    private final static QName _Test_QNAME = new Name("urn:vertexinc:enterprise:calendar:1:0", "Test");


    public ObjectFactory() {
    }
    public Test createTest() {
        return new Test();
    }

   }


    package test;

    public class Test {
    String name;
    String cls;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCls() {
        return cls;
    }

    public void setCls(String cls) {
        this.cls = cls;
    }

    }
```