# Generate XML Schema from Java class (or the opposite)

Tags: java, xsd

I wanted to generate some XML Schemas for my project. I have some Java Classes, like this one:

```
package com.fortresswars.entity;

import com.fortresswars.entity.properties.Armor;
import com.jme3.scene.Spatial;

public abstract class Object extends Thing {
    public Armor armor;
    public short hpMax;
    public boolean walkable = false;

    public short hpCurrent;
    public boolean alive;
    public Spatial object;

    public GameObject() {
        this.hpMax = hpMax;
        this.hpCurrent = hpMax;
    }

    public void setAlive(boolean alive) {
        this.alive = alive;
    }

    public void setHpCurrent(short hpCurrent) {
        this.hpCurrent = hpCurrent;
    }

    public void addHpCurrent(short hpToAdd) {
        this.hpCurrent += hpToAdd;
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.fortresswars.entity;

import com.jme3.texture.Image;
import eu.javaspecialists.tools.apt.NoArgsConstructor;

@NoArgsConstructor
public abstract class Thing {
    Image icon;

    public Thing() {
    }
}
```

I wanted to generate a XML Schema based on those classes for my project, so the other developers can build a XML file based on that generated Schema and they can validate the information before sending to me. But I don't know what is best, to generate a XML Schema based on a class, or generate a class based on a XML Schema. Please, could you point out what tools there is out there to do it, and the advantages of using each one of those approaches?

I know that there is a tool called JAXB, but I don't know if it does both of those jobs, or any of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JAXB can do both

1. [Using JAXB schemagen tooling to generate an XML schema file from a Java class](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/twbs_jaxbjava2schema.html)
2. [Using JAXB xjc tooling to generate JAXB classes from an XML schema file](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/twbs_jaxbschema2java.html)

Comment: Thank you. I've created an AntTask within my netbeans that generates the schema for my project, just for the interesting classes. It's perfect for my solution, spent about 2 hours to make this completly working.

Answer (score 4):

There's a tool called `schemagen` inside the JDK `bin` directory, that turns java source/class file into an XML schema.  See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/schemagen.html).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, JAXB can go both ways (using annotations). Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325048/pojo-to-xsd-generation) for more info and some links.