# Using spring integration and soap/rest as inbounds, can generate completely automatic their wsdl/wadl?

Tags: rest, soap, wsdl, spring-integration, wadl

(Maybe, there is hope)

If I have spring integration and as inbound soap or rest (http) is it possible to dynamically generate the wsdl and the wadl as in the classical approach?

(I have seen that you can expose the wsdl based on a given xsd - but I am interested in the api completely on its own generating these two 'contracts'...)

Answer (score 1):

Spring Integration uses Spring WebServices under the covers so you can use that to generate the WSDL from a schema as described in the [Spring WebServices Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-publishing-wsdl).

Comment: here, you have to give the xsd - I would like to completely generate the wsdl, so the xsd too, like cxf does...

Comment: Use JAXB to generate the schema - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720045/generate-xml-schema-from-java-class-or-the-opposite

Comment: it's not hard to generate it, but I guess it's hard to maintain this path. I would really like to have them automatically generated